# How to Recursively iterate through 2 lists

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

For my homework problem, I have to remove the duplicates in a list if part of the list is inside another. The expected outcome is supposed to be this:

```
(remove-redundant '((R (1 2 3 8 e 4 7 6 5))
                    (U (e 2 3 1 8 4 7 6 5))
                    (D (1 2 3 7 8 4 e 6 5)))

                  '((D (1 2 3 e 8 4 7 6 5))
                    (L (e 2 3 1 8 4 7 6 5))
                    (U (2 e 3 1 8 4 7 6 5))
                    (U (2 8 3 1 e 4 7 6 5))))
```

Returns:

```
((R (1 2 3 8 e 4 7 6 5)) (D (1 2 3 7 8 4 e 6 5)))
```

**It is supposed to check to see if the list inside each list, for the 1st parameter appears anywhere in the 2nd. If it does appear, then remove that from the 1st list. Basically, if (1 2 3 e 8 4 7 6 5) matches something in the 1st list, remove it from the 1st list. I need to do this recursively, it is supposed to be a functional program.**

I have already tried recursing through the list, but it doesn't reset (i.e. it will check the second list for the beginning of the first list but then will return.

```
(defun same-state (l1 l2)
   (if (equal (cadr l1) (cadr l2)) t nil))

(defun remove-redundant (l1 l2)
  (cond
     ((null l2) l1)
     ((null l1) nil)
     ((same-state (car l1) (car l2)) (remove-redundant (cdr l1) (cdr l2))
     (T (remove-redundant l1 (cdr l2)))))
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting issues: put newlines in, use apostrophes (`'`) instead of opening single quotes (`‘`), don't put parentheses on empty lines.  Then, please explain exactly why that U list is removed.

Comment: Minor point, but `(if x t nil)` is simply `x`

Comment: The U list is removed because the inside list (inside the 1st) matches an inside list in the 2nd list.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but there should be some accumulation of the cells you want to keep in the `t` case of your `cond` form, 
eg.

```
;; ...
(t
 (cons (car l1) (remove-redundant (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))
```

and when you check if the first element of `l1` exists in `l2` there should be another loop or recursion to check against all the elements in `l2`, eg.

```
(defun same-state (l1 l2)
  (find l1 l2 :key #'cadr :test #'equal))

(defun remove-redundant (l1 l2)
  (cond
    ((null l2) l1)
    ((null l1) nil)
    ((same-state (cadar l1) l2)
     (remove-redundant (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))
    (t (cons (car l1)
             (remove-redundant (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
;; => ((R (1 2 3 8 e 4 7 6 5)) (D (1 2 3 7 8 4 e 6 5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two loops: one to go through the first list, and then one per element of that to find matches in the second list.